# Finding matching elements in arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays of different lengths. For each element in `array_1`, I want to find the position of the matching element in `array_2`. This includes duplicates in `array_1`.

For example:

```py
array_1 = np.array([555, 641, 1000, 641, 4, 641])
array_2 = np.array([4, 555, 641, 1000])
```

The desired output would be:

```py
out = [1,2,3,2,0,2]
```

For every element in `array_1` there is a matching element in `array_2`. `array_2` is unique and sorted. In reality, each array has around a million terms.

The solution below works, but it is too slow for what I need:

```
out = [np.where(array_2 == x) for x in array_1]
```

Comment: Are the terms in the `array_2` unique and if not, do you want the position of its first occurence? Also, are all items of `array_1` guaranteed to be in `array_2`?

Comment: Your current solution is the worst case, where all items in `array_1` are unique. If there are many repeated values then a memoised solution would be faster (i.e. only check items from `array_1` that haven't already been checked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all unique items are present in both arrays.

if array_2 is sorted, then it's not even needed to use it, [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) is sufficient.

```
out = np.unique(array_1, return_inverse=True)[1]
```

Output: `array([1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2])`

If `array_2` is not sorted, then one needs a bit of post-processing with [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
# let's take a non sorted example
array_2 = np.array([555, 641, 4, 1000])

uniq, idx = np.unique(array_1, return_inverse=True)

out = np.argsort(array_2)[idx]
```

Output: `array([0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1])`

Comment: Sorry I think my question was unclear. The elements in array_2 are unique and sorted but are not in order. Will edit my question to reflect that

Comment: @Matildes if array_2 is sorted and `set(array_1) == set(array_2)`, then `np.unique(array_1, return_inverse=True)[1]` is a valid solution ;)

Comment: What is your `array_1` in this solution?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2 arrays be compared? From my understanding your solution uses array_1 only

Comment: @jared `array_1` as defined in the question

Comment: @Matildes that's exactly what I explained in my answer. You do not need knowledge of `array_2`. In fact, if you run `a, idx = np.unique(array_1, return_inverse=True)`, `a` is `array_2` and `idx` your expected output. Please try this with your data if you do not trust me ;)

Comment: @mozway So your `array_2 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])` was just an example of an unsorted `array_2`? It might be clearer if you took the `array_2` from the question and mixed it up a little, e.g. `array_2 = np.array([555, 641, 4, 1000])`. Otherwise, really interesting solution. I did not think you could get the result from `np.unique`.

Comment: @jared I'll make that more explicit, also the values were `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in the original question, I forgot to change.

Comment: @mozway Gotcha, I didn't realize the numbers had changed.

Comment: @jared It should be more explicit now.

Comment: @mozway thank you it worked!! Just curious would argsort work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
np.nonzero(np.equal.outer(array_1, array_2))[1]
```

Always vectorise when possible.

Comment: It raises the following error: 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 31.0 GiB for an array with shape (180490, 184184) and data type bool'

Comment: That's fairly expected, since this is a full broadcast. It works for your sample input. If you want it to work for massive input you need to change your question's MCVE.

Comment: OP mentioned that "*both arrays are around a million terms long*", which would create an intermediate with 1 trillion items ;) @Matildes can you clarify if `array_2` is sorted and if the unique items of both arrays are equal? How many unique items do you have?

Comment: array_2 is sorted. The unique items of both arrays are equal but I also need to count duplicates in array_1. The number of unique numbers is not fixed but should be of order hundreds of thousands.

Comment: OK, then my first solution is valid and will be very fast.